# Accessing looped json data (Ajax)

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

In the data sample below, I'm trying to loop through and grab al data from the `participants` section.

Through an ajax call I'm able to access the other data as follows, but I can't figure out the for statement for this data.

```
var userData = $.ajax({ 
    type: "POST",
    url: userurl,
    dataType: "json",
    //data: { point: point, claimId: id, type: val,follow: followuser }
    })
    .success(function(json) {
      $.each(json.data, function(i,x){
        var id = x.Claim.user_id; // ETC
                    ...
```

This works great.  Using this format, I can access individual data like this: `x.participants[8].user_id`.  I just can't figure out how to loop `participants` to grab all participant user_ids, for example.

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "Claim": {
            "img_url": null,
            "id": "4",
            "user_id": "3",
            "claim_status": "started",
            "exp": "Sep 30, 2013"
        },
        "User": {
            "score": "0",
            "id": "3"
         },
        "ClaimResponse": [
            {
                "id": "32",
                "claim_id": "4",
                "user_id": "14",
                "created": "2013-06-10 03:18:35",
                "modified": "2013-06-10 03:18:35"
            },
            {
                "id": "107",
                "claim_id": "4",
                "user_id": "8",
                "created": "2013-06-28 02:37:10",
                "modified": "2013-06-28 02:37:10"
            },
            {
                "id": "140",
                "claim_id": "4",
                "user_id": "976",
                "created": "2013-06-28 04:19:22",
                "modified": "2013-06-28 04:19:22"
            },
            {
                "id": "152",
                "claim_id": "4",
                "user_id": "19",
                "created": "2013-07-03 02:27:12",
                "modified": "2013-07-03 02:27:12"
            },
            {
                "id": "154",
                "claim_id": "4",
                "user_id": "1158",
                "created": "2013-07-05 03:16:48",
                "modified": "2013-07-05 03:16:48"
            }
        ],
        "participants": {
            "14": {
                "user_id": "14",
                "twitter_image_url": "https://si0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_1_normal.png"
            },
            "8": {
                "user_id": "8",
                "twitter_image_url": "https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_3_normal.png"
            },
            "19": {
                "user_id": "19",
                "twitter_image_url": "https://si0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_2_normal.png"
            },
            "1158": {
                "user_id": "1158",
                "twitter_image_url": "https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_5_normal.png"
            }
        },
        "viewer": {
            "isResponsed": false,
            "isOwner": false,
            "lockedInPoint": 0,
            "response": null,
            "cut_loss": false,
            "cut_loss_price": null
        }
    },
    {
        "Claim": {
            "img_url": null,
            "id": "133",
            "user_id": "14",
            "claim_status": "started",
            "exp": "Jul 15, 2013"
        },
        "User": {
            "score": "-40",
            "id": "14"
        },
        "ClaimResponse": [
            {
                "id": "172",
                "claim_id": "133",
                "user_id": "8",
                "created": "2013-07-12 20:36:16",
                "modified": "2013-07-12 20:36:16"
            },
            {
                "id": "176",
                "claim_id": "133",
                "user_id": "1159",
                "created": "2013-07-13 02:52:31",
                "modified": "2013-07-13 02:52:31"
            }
        ],
        "participants": {
            "8": {
                "user_id": "8",
               "twitter_image_url": "https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_5_normal.png"

            },
            "1159": {
                "user_id": "1159",
               "twitter_image_url": "https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_5_normal.png"

            }
        },
        "viewer": {
            "isResponsed": false,
            "isOwner": false,
            "lockedInPoint": 0,
            "response": null,
            "cut_loss": false,
            "cut_loss_price": null
        }
    }
],
"errors": [],
"success": true,
"code": 200
}
```

**EDIT:**  A fiddle, thanks to the help of @ohgodwhy.  Maybe this better illustrates what I'm trying to do. I'd like the participant icons associated with their respective claim. It's close, but seems to be pulling in all the participants from the first claim...:

http://jsfiddle.net/gkGP4/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, of course, was WHERE my loop was.  I was looping too soon and calling all my initially iterated variables d times (d being the number of items in my nested loop).

Here's the solution:

```
var d = {
"data": [{
    "Claim": {
        "img_url": null,
            "id": "4",
            "user_id": "3",
            "claim_status": "started",
            "exp": "Sep 30, 2013"
    },
        "User": {
        "score": "0",
            "id": "3"
    },
        "ClaimResponse": [{
        "id": "32",
            "claim_id": "4",
            "user_id": "14",
            "created": "2013-06-10 03:18:35",
            "modified": "2013-06-10 03:18:35"
    }, {
        "id": "107",
            "claim_id": "4",
            "user_id": "8",
            "created": "2013-06-28 02:37:10",
            "modified": "2013-06-28 02:37:10"
    }, {
        "id": "140",
            "claim_id": "4",
            "user_id": "976",
            "created": "2013-06-28 04:19:22",
            "modified": "2013-06-28 04:19:22"
    }, {
        "id": "152",
            "claim_id": "4",
            "user_id": "19",
            "created": "2013-07-03 02:27:12",
            "modified": "2013-07-03 02:27:12"
    }, {
        "id": "154",
            "claim_id": "4",
            "user_id": "1158",
            "created": "2013-07-05 03:16:48",
            "modified": "2013-07-05 03:16:48"
    }],
        "participants": {
        "14": {
            "user_id": "14",
                "twitter_image_url": "https://si0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_1_normal.png"
        },
            "8": {
            "user_id": "8",
                "twitter_image_url": "https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_3_normal.png"
        },
            "19": {
            "user_id": "19",
                "twitter_image_url": "https://si0.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_2_normal.png"
        },
            "1158": {
            "user_id": "1158",
                "twitter_image_url": "https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_5_normal.png"
        }
    },
        "viewer": {
        "isResponsed": false,
            "isOwner": false,
            "lockedInPoint": 0,
            "response": null,
            "cut_loss": false,
            "cut_loss_price": null
    }
}, {
    "Claim": {
        "img_url": null,
            "id": "133",
            "user_id": "14",
            "claim_status": "started",
            "exp": "Jul 15, 2013"
    },
        "User": {
        "score": "-40",
            "id": "14"
    },
        "ClaimResponse": [{
        "id": "172",
            "claim_id": "133",
            "user_id": "8",
            "created": "2013-07-12 20:36:16",
            "modified": "2013-07-12 20:36:16"
    }, {
        "id": "176",
            "claim_id": "133",
            "user_id": "1159",
            "created": "2013-07-13 02:52:31",
            "modified": "2013-07-13 02:52:31"
    }],
        "participants": {
        "8": {
            "user_id": "8",
                "twitter_image_url": "https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_5_normal.png"

        },
            "1159": {
            "user_id": "1159",
                "twitter_image_url": "https://twimg0-a.akamaihd.net/sticky/default_profile_images/default_profile_5_normal.png"

        }
    },
        "viewer": {
        "isResponsed": false,
            "isOwner": false,
            "lockedInPoint": 0,
            "response": null,
            "cut_loss": false,
            "cut_loss_price": null
    }
}],
    "errors": [],
    "success": true,
    "code": 200
}
    $.each(d.data, function (i, x) {
id = x.Claim.id;

    $('body').append('<div class="id"><p id="img'+x.Claim.id+'">Claim' + x.Claim.id + '</p></div>');
   $.each(x.participants, function (i, p) {
   $('#img'+x.Claim.id).append('<img src="' + p.twitter_image_url + '"/>');
});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/gkGP4/6/

Thanks to all for the various approaches.

Answer (score 0):

The `data` array contains a single object that contains all the other data, so you should loop through `json.data[0]` rather than `json.data`.

As you have a mix of objects containing data directly, arrays containing objects, and objects containing objects, you have to loop through the items in different ways to find the properties:

```
var ids = [];
$.each(json.data[0], function(i, x) {
  if (x.hasOwnProperty('user_id') {
    ids.push(x.user_id);
  } else {
    $.each(x, function(j, y) {
      if (y.hasOwnProperty('user_id') {
        ids.push(y.user_id);
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You must select the index of the data object within your returned JSON. Then, once you have that, you can iterate the participants. This is because the `data` is an `array` when being returned, so we need to select the index of the data at which the objects exist. if you don't supply it, you will get `undefined`.

```
$.each(json.data[0].participants, function(i,p){
    //access p with properties
    console.log(p.twitter_image_url); //twitter image url
    console.log(p.user_id); //user's id
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vPa4n/)

Comment: Hi- Thanks so much @ohgodwhy. This gets me very close.  I actually have multiple `Claim` objects within my json, with individual `participant` objects associated with each. I'm trying to use your example to get at all of them, somewhat like `$.each(x.participants, function(i,p){`. This gets them for me, but I'm having trouble attaching them to each claim.  I've modified the data in my original post to show two claims, each with participants, and I'm trying to return Claim id2: Participants 14 8 18 1158.  Claim id133: Participants 8, 1159.  I'll pluck away at it, but I'd love your thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a result set containing claimid and associated participant ids

```
var result = $.map(response.data, function(item){
    return { ClaimId : item.Claim.id, Participants: $.map(item.participants, function(item1){ return item1.user_id; }) };
});
console.log(result);
```

hope this helps.